# Зациклить вывод индекса в массиве JavaScript

Tags: javascript, циклы

Помогите пожалуйста дописать js код, как зациклить вывод индекса массива, чтобы он начинался с "первого слова", а когда доходил до "третьего", начинал опять "с первого" ?

```
   function clickbutton (){
     var words = [
      "Первое слово",
      "Второе слово",
      "Третье слово"
                ];
      ???
    document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = ???;
       }
```

Comment: и сколько раз он так должен вывести? какой результат вывода должен быть для приведенного кода?

Comment: Выводит в тег HTML значение массива, при нажатии кнопки

Comment: добавь это пояснение в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myArray = ["Первое слово", "Второе слово",
  "Третье слово", "Четвертое слово"
];
var myIndex = 1;
var print = document.getElementById('print');

print.innerHTML = myArray[0]; //Print first value of array right away.

function nextElement() {
  print.innerHTML = myArray[myIndex];
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex == 3) {
    myIndex = 0;
  }

  (myIndex + 1) % (myArray.length);
};
```

```html
<p>слова: <span id="print"></span>.</p>

<a id="click" href="#" onclick="nextElement();">Click</a>
```

Comment: Без `alert`а не взлетит.

Comment: @Qwertiy, перестарался)

Comment: И? Это вечный цикл и страница перерисовываться не будет.

Comment: про перерисовывание страницы ничего не сказанно, заголовок гласит: "Зациклить вывод индекса в массиве JavaScript"

Comment: `.innerHTML =` - не перерисуется в случае цикла.

Comment: У кого завис браузер?

Comment: @EugenEray все больше не зависнет, завис не зря, это же зацикленный массив

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko  А, точно.

Comment: не выводит в HTML значения массива, что добавить: document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = words[???];

Comment: @JayMorgan, поменял пример

Comment: не работает, странно почему, скопировал все как есть

Comment: @JayMorgan, это уже у вас какая то проблема, тут все работает

Comment: Все класс, скрипт просто поставил после  id="print" и все заработало, спасибо вам большое !

Answer (score 0):

Используй в качестве индекса `i % words.length`.